# What is ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint used for?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy

Can someone explain what ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint is intended to be used for?  I have been writing some code to work with proxies in C#, and have seen indicators that it might be useful in this respect, but can't see why or how.  How is this class (ServicePointManager) or method (ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint) supposed to be used (or when)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(...)` method will help you get the `ServicePoint` object that you've been specified in the configuration file.

Let's say, this is your configuration file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
   <add address="http://www.contoso.com" maxconnection="2" />
   <add address="192.168.1.2" maxconnection="4" />
   <add address="*" maxconnection="1" />
  </connectionManagement>
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```

This code would retrieve the "http://www.microsoft.com" `ServicePoint`:

```
ServicePoint sp1 = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com"));
```

Comment: The last hyperlink is broken.